# Design to fetch DB data and load in jsp while application starting

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

We just started our development using jsp's and spring mvc framework. Looking for a good approach to load data from DB and save all the jsp page data into DB. Here is the brief description:

1. As there is no login details yet decided, When I start my application, this loads my jsp page which we are working on. This jsp page contains 4 to 5 sections.  Each and every section requires some preloaded data which should come from DB.
2. We need to load and display this data while loading the jsp page itself.
3. Once the jsp page is loaded with all the pre-populated values from DB, there will be other fields where user enter some data and finally Save this jsp page.

I have around 8 to 9 drop-down lists in jsp which should get loaded from DB. How I can load all this data while loading the page ? Can I load all this data once from db and put it as part of one object and display as part of jsp ?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView visitHome(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Testing purpose");
    return new ModelAndView("first");
}
```

As we are using Spring MVC framework here, I am redirecting from jsp to controller as above, and then to service then to DAO then to DB. How I can include all the DB loading logic as part of above method ?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some pojos and return pojos with model and view. Assume that you have class SectionData and you want to set some data to it and return it with view.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView visitHome(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

            SectionData sectionData = new SectionData();
            sectionData.setName("John Citizen");

            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.addObject("firstSectionData", sectionData);
            modelAndView.setViewName("first");

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

And then you can bind jsp elements with section data such as

My name is ${firstSectionData.name}

Now the HTML page will show "My name is John Citizen".